# MySQL query to display rows as columns if ID matches

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I'm trying to massage some data for a CSV import and I'm having some issues.

My table with sample data:

```
node_id, comment

1,comment1
1,comment2
2,comment3
3,comment4
4,comment5
4,comment6
4,comment7
```

What I would like to do is run a query that puts all comments with the same node_id in a single row:

```
1,comment1,comment2
2,comment3
3,comment4
4,comment5,comment6,comment7
```

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: The way you want to import the data is not normalized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT node_id, GROUP_CONCAT(comment) FROM sample_data_table GROUP BY node_id;
```

**Note:** This table structure actually de-normalizes data. Which could be a poor design decision down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT, check [this](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) example for more